# There are n people at a party. Prove that there are two of them such that among the remaining n − 2 people there are at least [n/2] - 1,

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

There are $n$ people at a party. Prove that there are two of them such that among the
remaining $n − 2$ people there are at least $[n/2] - 1$, each of whom knows both or else
knows neither of the two.

Denote by $T$ the set of ordered triples of people $(a, b, c)$ such that $c$ is either a common
acquaintance of both $a$ and $b$ or unknown to both $a$ and $b$. If $c$ knows exactly $k$ participants,
then there exist exactly $2k(n − 1 − k)$ ordered pairs in which $c$ knows exactly one of $a$ and $b$
(the factor $2$ shows up because we work with ordered pairs). There will be
$(n − 1)(n − 2) − 2k(n − 1 − k) ≥ (n − 1)(n − 2) − 2(n-1)^2/4 = (n-1)(n-3)/2$ ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $c$ knows either both or neither of $a$ and $b$.
Counting by the $c$’s, we find that the number of elements of  satisfies
$|T| >= n(n-1)(n-3)/2$

To apply the pigeonhole principle, we let the “holes” be the ordered pairs of people $(a, b)$,
and the “pigeons” be the triples $(a, b, c) ∈ T$. Put the pigeon $(a, b, c)$ in the hole $(a, b)$ if $c$
knows either both or neither of $a$ and $b$. There are f$n(n − 1)(n − 3)/2$ pigeons distributed in
$n(n − 1)$ holes. So there will be at least

$[(n(n-1)(n-3)/2)/n(n-1)] = [n/2] - 1$

The aforementioned text only includes a part of the entire solution.
Can you explain (a little in detail) why we have $2k(n-1-k)$ ordered pairs.
Also, what exactly does the last equality mean?
Any other comments explaining the solution are also welcome.

Comment: I think you'll find the ability to [use mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here valuable.

Answer (score 1):

I can help with your first question.

If the person knows $k$ people, then the person doesn't know $n-1-k$ people.

There are a total of $(n-1)(n-2)$ ordered pairs of the remaining people. There are $k(k-1)$ ordered pairs that the person knows both, and $(n-k-1)(n-k-2)$ ordered pairs that the person doesn't know either.

All of the remaining pairs the person knows exactly one of the pair. So, subtracting we have

$(n-1)(n-2) - k(k-1) - (n-k-1)(n-k-2) = 2k(n-1-k)$ pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down that last paragraph:

- There are $n(n-1)(n-3)/2$ pigeons, which are the triples $(a, b, c)$.
- There are $ n(n-1) $ holes, where are $(a, b)$.
- We assign a pigeon to a hole if the first 2 coordinates match.
- By PP, there is a hole with at least $ \lceil \frac{ \text{ # pigeons} } { \text{ # holes } } \rceil = \lceil \frac {n(n-1)(n-3)/2} {n(n-1) }   \rceil  $ pigeons.
- Since $\lceil \frac {n(n-1)(n-3)/2} {n(n-1) }   \rceil  = \lceil \frac {n-3} {2 }   \rceil = [n/2 ] - 1$, the conditions of the question are satisfied.

Note: The last equality was not explicitly proven, just stated. If you have difficulty with it, show your work.
Yes, you have to figure out whether they want floor or ceiling of $n/2$.